# How to separate inner polygon and outer polygon from a list of points in C#

Tags: c#, polygon, shapes, system.drawing

Assume a polygon like below

[image: polygon drawn using list of points]

I have shape like above and the list of points which are of any order

```
Point[] polygon = { A(x,y), B (x,y) ..... L(x,y) }
```

I need to separate the outer polygon and inner polygon points.

```
Point[] outerpoly = { A(x,y), B(x,y), C(x,y)... H(x,y) }

Point[] innerpoly = { I(x,y), J(x,y), K(x,y), L(x,y) }
```

For the purpose of algorithm we can assume the `Point` can be in `System.Windows.Point` or `System.Drawing.Point`.

Please help me find an algorithm to get the list of points of inner and outer polygon.

Comment: If you only have a list of points in any order, there would be multiple ways to sort them into two rings. Like in your example, there are many combinations.

Comment: @TimTim Wong, true. That's the problem. Im hoping I can separate them as closed polygons, in case of the example, 2 closed polygons.

Comment: Polygons are of course closed. I mean it could be ABCFGHLI and DEKJ, or other combinations.

Comment: So not possible then??

Comment: Yep, no deterministic solution.

Comment: Thanks @TimTim Wong

Comment: Exactly how closely will the polygons resemble your drawing? Can you provide some sample points?

Comment: @NetMage , The polygons will have corners and edges. Inner and outer polygons will have corners and edges. Ideally...Can be of any shape with edges and corners.

Comment: I would start by reducing the number of candidate points. The outermost ones - biggest and smallest for x & y. Then you can do something with lines crossing between 2 pairs of points. Lines between each shape's connected points will not cross lines between any others.

Answer (score 0):

Using a coordinate system where increasing values go down and to the right, you can just sort and select the points for each polygon.

Create `List<Point>`s to store the results:

```
var outerpoly = new List<Point>();
var innerpoly = new List<Point>();
```

Now sort the points vertically for the initial selections:

```
var vertical = polygon.OrderByDescending(p => p.Y).ToList();
```

Then for each section, sort them horizontally and extract what you need.

First, the outer polygon:

```
var outerBottom = vertical.Take(2).OrderBy(p => p.X);    
outerpoly.AddRange(outerBottom);

var outerRightBottomIn = vertical.Skip(2).Take(4).OrderByDescending(p => p.X).Take(2);
outerpoly.AddRange(outerRightBottomIn);

var outerRightTopOut = vertical.Skip(8).Take(2).OrderBy(p => p.X);
outerpoly.AddRange(outerRightTopOut);

var outerTop = vertical.Skip(10).OrderByDescending(p => p.X);
outerpoly.AddRange(outerTop);
```

Then the inner polygon:

```
var innerBottom = vertical.Skip(2).Take(4).OrderBy(p => p.X).Take(2);
innerpoly.AddRange(innerBottom);

var innerTop = vertical.Skip(6).Take(2).OrderByDescending(p => p.X);
innerpoly.AddRange(innerTop);
```

Comment: Let me confirm @NetMage

Comment: I ran the test but the result is not as expected. Please let me know if you need more info.